# ResultSet not updatable

Tags: java, sql, database, resultset, delete-row

I am doing a simple GUI application in Java (NetBeans 7.3.1) in which I use ResultSet for retreiving and updating data in the virtual database of NetBeans.

I created the database "Employees" and a table, "WORKERS", in it. Tough, I can't update data in it.

The code is

```
public void doConnect() {
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
    String uName = "adm";
    String uPass = "admin";
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM APP.WORKERS ORDER BY ID";
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
        int conc = rs.getConcurrency();
        System.out.println(conc);
        rs.next();
        int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
        String first_name = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String last_name = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");
        System.out.println(id_col + " " + first_name + " " + last_name + " " + job);
        textId.setText(Integer.toString(id_col));
        textName.setText(first_name);
        textLast.setText(last_name);
        txtJob.setText(job);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The outcome of `getConcurrency();` is 1007 (ReadOnly).
What did I wrong? I can't find the error.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it because you make the result set updatable after `rs.deleteRow();` ?
maybe if you place

```
stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

before the `rs.deleteRow();` it works.

Comment: I did it after `rs.deleteRow();` because i `close` the rs and the stmt and then re-create them.

Comment: I see, maybe your driver doesn't support your result set to be updatable, it will set your result set to readonly, you can check this with: int concurrency = rs.getConcurrency(); if it is ReadOnly the outcome is: 1007, if it is updatable it is: 1008

Comment: tough it IS updatable, because I can insert data into that table.

Comment: hmm, you're right, can you try deleteRow() in another method to see if it depends on the deleteRow() or the method (context) ?

Comment: I re-checked all the program and now every method generates this exception. It says that's ReadOnly, even if I declared it CONCUR_UPDATABLE.

Comment: EDIT: I tried `int concurrency = rs.getConcurrency();` just after the declaration of the ResultSet, the outcome is 1007. I'm going mad.

Comment: Found it. The query can't be `SELECT * FROM APP.WORKERS ORDER BY ID`, it must be `SELECT * FROM APP.WORKERS`.

Comment: It can be the version of your servers driver or maybe the problems lays in the connection.

Comment: is your problem solved now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write inside your try catch clause under your variable con this line:

```
con.setReadOnly(false);
```

If this does not solve the problem, you must find a way to access the database options within NetBeans and make sure the access and use of database objects is set to editable/updateable/read and write. I cannot help more since I use Eclipse and my NetBeans skills are a bit rusty.

Comment: The problem is in the query. I can't order it and then modify, I only can do a select.

Comment: Try this solution: change the "Select *" to only be "Select (nameOfColumnHere,nameOfColumnHere,....)" it might help

Comment: No, it doesn't work. If I do a query containing "ORDER BY" it makes my resultSet ReadOnly.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure if this will help anything in regular SQL but u might wanna try it; SELECT * FROM APP.WORKERS WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY ID ASC

Comment: ok then I guess it only works with t-sql :( I guess if u wanted to update data into the table you might want to first do a SELECT to figure out which column you want to update, and based on that do another sql UPDATE/INSERT INTO query WHERE ID=x

Comment: Indeed, I did that :)